Seemingly innocuous question deleted after being flagged as spam or offensive content
I was surprised to see that a recent question about the sector/industry classification of prison stocks was suddenly deleted.
I understand that prison stocks are controversial but the question isn't inherently spam or offensive just because a few people don't like it.
What's the standard for "offensive content" and how does it apply here?

The question was deleted primarily because of other activity by the user giving signal that it was not a genuine question (I can't really go into any more detail on that). But given you had an upvoted answer this was a bit unfair on you so I've undeleted it now.

Thank you for the context and undeleting the answer!
